# Gmail call, available or not?

Tags: gmail

I tried the new [Gmail call feature](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2010/08/25/gmail-phone-calls-coming-_n_693701.html)  and it worked fine the first time. I have 2 Gmail accounts. At first, the `call button` was only showing in one account. Now it isn't showing in either.

Any idea why?

[image: Screenshot of call UI]

Comment: Are you sure you added the feature to both accounts?

Comment: yes, it was working in one account and now its not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read on the [BBC news](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-11092212) that Google announced this feature and mistakenly enabled it for every user, only to then remove it from non US accounts later that day:

> "Unintentionally we briefly made the service available to non-US English users," a spokesperson said. "We do hope to bring it to our international users soon."
>
> When it rolls out the product link will appear on the left hand of the Gmail page within the "chat" window. A "call phone" option will pop up along with a number pad to let you dial the number of the person you want to talk to.

If your account is not US based, it may explain why you could do it but now cannot.

Comment: Can you link the source?

Comment: @rchern I was going to when I answered, but couldn't find it. I've just have another look and found it - see updated answer.

Comment: exact, now its showing the 'button' when i set my language to English(US)

Answer (score 6):

Google generally does phased roll outs, so there are often some people with a new feature and others waiting.  I would wait a few days and see if it appears.

Comment: yes but i had the feature i tried it and it worked fine but the call button suddenly dissapeared and i have no more button o_O

Comment: Are you sure it was on both accounts? :|

Answer (score 2):

Set you language to be English(US) and then that should add in the ability to call

Answer (score 0):

I tried it the day it rolled out, and it worked for my wife, it worked on my secondary account, but not my main one, the one I've been using with Google Voice since it was still Grand Central. Eventually, it started working.

Do you still have the problem?

Comment: its working when i've set language to English(US) as Lach and adrianbanks recommended

Answer (score 0):

If your accounts are not US based, you may still be able to use the GMail call feature.  http://gadgetwise.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/08/30/does-googles-free-phone-service-work-in-other-countries/?partner=rss&emc=rss